# Angularjs autocomplete ng-click does not work

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I'm trying to write autocomplete in Angularjs. It works for me except the click on the suggestion. From the console log it looks like whenever I click on the suggestion, ng-blur of the input element is called as it input element loses focus and ng-click is never called. Can anybody suggest a solution here?

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete</title>
    <style>.wrapper {display: none;}.wrapper ul {list-style-type: none;}.wrapper li {padding: 5px;line-height: 25px;cursor: pointer;}</style>
    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ng-controller="SuggestionCtrl">
        <form action="/index.html">
            <input type="search" name="q"  autocomplete="off" 
                ng-model="q" 
                ng-focus="showSuggesions()"
                ng-blur="hideSuggesions()" 
                ng-change="getSuggestion()">
            <div class="wrapper"
                ng-if="hasSuggestions"
                ng-style="suggestionStyle">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions"
                        ng-click="search(suggestion)">
                        {{suggestion}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("SuggestionCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.suggestions = ["India", "United States", "England", "Australia"];

    $scope.showSuggesions = function () {
        $scope.suggestionStyle = { display: "block", 'background-color': '#ddd' };
    };

    $scope.hideSuggesions = function () {
        $scope.suggestionsVisible = false;
        $scope.suggestionStyle = { display: "none" };
        console.log('hideSuggestions called');
    };

    $scope.hasSuggestions = function(){
        return $scope.suggestions.length > 0;
    }

    $scope.getSuggestion = function () {
        // get suggestions from api
    };

    $scope.search = function (suggestion) {
        window.location = window.location + "?q=" + suggestion;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` event executes after `blur` - list with suggestions hides before you are able to click it. The simple solution is to use `mousedown` instead of `click`

```
<input type="search" name="q"  autocomplete="off" 
            ng-model="q" 
            ng-focus="show=true" 
            ng-blur="show=false">
            <div class="wrapper"
            ng-style="suggestionStyle">
            <ul ng-show="show">
                <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions">
                    <a ng-mousedown="search(suggestion)">{{suggestion}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4e4dYD4qJZwnNRmgWiN?p=preview